# Curl not working inside node, however getting inside a container - Jenkinsfile

Tags: kubernetes, curl, jenkins-pipeline

I am able to do curl inside a container however not able to access curl from node level. This is my code.

```
def label = "myPod-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"
def serviceaccount = "mySvc"
podTemplate(label: label, serviceAccount: serviceaccount,
                containers: [containerTemplate(name: 'my-container', image: 'wwwwwwwww:yyy', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat')],
                   imagePullSecrets: ['xxxx'])

{
    node(label){
        container('my-container') {
            sh "echo FROM CONTAINER"
            sh "curl --version"
            //sh (script: "curl --version", returnStdout: true).trim();
        }
        
        sh "echo OUTSIDE CONTAINER"
        sh "curl --version"
    }
}
```

**my-container** is not using a curl image, however I am able to access but not from the node. The output from Jenkins console is something like this.

```
+ echo FROM CONTAINER
FROM CONTAINER
[Pipeline] sh
+ curl --version
curl 7.77.0 (x86_64-alpine-linux-musl) libcurl/7.77.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1k zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 nghttp2/1.42.0
Release-Date: 2021-05-26
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo OUTSIDE CONTAINER
OUTSIDE CONTAINER
[Pipeline] sh
+ curl --version
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/sample@tmp/durable-a94a75f9/script.sh: 1: curl: not found
```

From the Jenkins pod log it seems that it is spinning up an agent in which the job is running where it is not finding curl. However the Jenkins pod has curl installed in it.

The output of $PATH

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ whoami
jenkins
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo /opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[Pipeline] sh
+ whereis curl
curl:
[Pipeline] container
```

Can anyone please help on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems there's no `curl` binary on the `node` you run the pipeline. You have only `curl` available in your `my-container` Docker image.

Comment: Hi Marcin thanks for your reply! How to add curl in the node in runtime? Cannot even install curl on the fly as the pod is running as jenkins user.

Comment: Instead of relying on the `curl` binary, you can replace it with the [`httpRequest` pipeline step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/#httprequest-perform-an-http-request-and-return-a-response-object). This way it will be available regardless the container used in the pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

Check the `PATH` environment variable. Jenkins by default resets it to quite the basic. Only `/bin:/usr/bin` is used if my memory serves me well. If cUrl is installed elsewhere you either have to call it using the full path or expand Jenkins’ path definition.

Printing `$PATH` will give you the current value. Compare this to the install location of curl.

---

The image `wwwwwwwww:yyy` does come with the alpine version of curl. So during the install process it was installed as a direct or indirect dependency.

The Jenkins Agent that is launched on the side, runs on a container without curl installed. If you want to have curl (or any other binary) installed you have two options:

- installing during runtime using e.g. the custom tools plugin
- install during the image creation. If you followed the instructions of https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin, you ended up using the `jenkins/inbound-agent` image. You can extend the image and publish it in a private registry the Kubernetes cluster has access to. Change your config to point to this image instead.

This could be your `Dockerfile` for a start:

```
FROM jenkins/inbound-agent:latest-alpine-jdk8
USER root
RUN apk add –no-cache curl
USER jenkins
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan thanks for your reply! When running the job from jenkins it is creating a agent pod(having a different image) on the fly where it is trying to access curl however curl is installed in the master which I can see and working as well.

Comment: Please add `sh "echo $PATH"` to the steps of the pipeline and paste the output to your question. Also please list where curl is installled.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I have not downvoted, not sure why it is showing. Even I cannot change it as I need 15 reputation to do that.

Comment: I have added the output of $PATH in the question. Curl is not installed in the container and as it is running as jenkins user hence it does not have the permission to install curl.